# Load New View Controller Instead of Presenting Temporary

Tags: objective-c

I have the below code which I wanted to use to load a new view controller after the user enters the app via a login form. The problem with this implementation is that when I load the new view, it's own navigation bar doesn't appear on the screen, I think because i the purpose of this function is temporary presentation, when the user can switch back to the previous view. My question is how could I load the other view to display its on navigation bar and don't let the user to go back to the previous view (login area)?

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *homeViewNavigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab"];
[homeViewNavigationController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:homeViewNavigationController  animated:animated completion:nil];
```

Comment: Your approach is backwards. Pretend for a moment that your app doesn't need a login screen. Setup your app to initially show the app's main view controller as the root view controller. Now you can deal with the login. If, upon startup, you determine that a login is needed, present the login screen from the main root view. When the login is complete and the login view controller is dismissed, the main view becomes visible again without any need to for any weird changes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok one possible solution can be hide the navigation controller before pushing new views into the view hierarchy.

```
[homeViewNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621885-setnavigationbarhidden?language=objc